# sequence-point warning using pack expansion when assigning to tuple

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++17

```
// https://godbolt.org/z/e7ebq6hYE

int print(std::string str, int i){
    std::cout << i << str << std::endl;
    return i;
}

template<typename ... Args>
void concat(Args ... args) {
    int i = 2;
    std::tuple<int, int, int, int> ret { print("ss", -22), print(args, i++) ... }; // gcc warning
    std::vector<int> ret1 { print("ss", -22), print(args, i++) ... };
}

int main()
{
    concat("a", "b", "c");
}
```

> warning: operation on 'i' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]

For the above code only gcc seem to think there is an issue with `i++` in pack expansion, and only when the assignment is for a tuple. clang seems to compile and run without warnings.

Is it a bug in gcc or is clang not reporting this warning?

Comment: Where do you have fold expression here ? `print(args,i++)...` is just unpacking args parameter pack. Fold will be: `(print(args, i++),...)`. But then, tuple ctor gets 2 ints, instead 4.

Comment: @rafix07 Thanks for the tip, ill correct the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning is wrong, see rule (10) [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order):

> In list-initialization, every value computation and side effect of a given initializer clause is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with any initializer clause that follows it in the brace-enclosed comma-separated list of initalizers.

The rule should equally affect brace initiailization of tuples and vectors.

---

Note that this is not a fold expression, just a pack expansion.

Comment: What's the difference between a fold expression and a pack expansion?

Comment: @ZoomIn A regular pack expansion looks like `expr...`. A fold expression looks like `(expr + ... )` or `(... + expr)` or `(expr + ... + expr)` (where `+` can be almost any binary operator). It seems that fold expressions are a subset of pack expansions.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65866